# how to display the nut,date fields in html template ? how to access foreign key fields in html tamplate?

Tags: html, django, templates, view, model

I have three models in models.py which are Topic,Webpage and AccessRecord. class AccessRecord has foreign key relation with class Webpage i wanna use AccessRecord fields nut,date in html template which is used to display class Webpage content how we can access AccessRecord fields in which has a foreign relation with class Webpage ?

**this is my model**:

```
    class Topic(models.Model):
        top_name = models.CharField(max_length=264,unique=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.top_name

    class Webpage(models.Model):
        topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=264,unique=True)
        url = models.URLField(unique=True)

    

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

    class AccessRecord(models.Model):
        name = models.ForeignKey(Webpage)
        date = models.DateField()
        nut = models.CharField(max_length=56)

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.date)
```

**this is my view**:

```
    def index(request):
        webpage_list = Webpage.objects.all()
        web_dict = {"web_records":webpage_list}
        return render(request,'first_app/index.html',web_dict)
```

**this is my template**:

```
    <body>
    <h1>Hi, welcome to Django Level Two!</h1>
    <h2>Here are your access records:</h2>
    <div class="djangtwo">
      {% if web_records %}
      <table style="float: left">
          <thead>
              <th>Topic Name</th>
              <th>Site name</th>
              <th>Url Accessed</th>
              <th>Date Accessed</th>
              <th>Webpage nut</th>
          </thead>
      {% for web in web_records %}
      <tr>
          <td>{{ web.topic }}</td>
          <td>{{ web.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ web.url }}</td>
          <td>{{ web.nut }}</td>
          <td>{{ web.date }}</td>
     </tr>
     {% endfor %}
    </table>
     {% endif %}
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Why don't you move the nut & date fields in webpage model instead of creating another model for two fields? It will be efficient.

Comment: i know that but i wanna know how to access the foreign key fields

Answer (score 0):

You can also make views.py like

```
#views.py

def index(request):
    return render(request,'first_app/index.html')
```

AND modify template like:-

```
    <body>
<h1>Hi, welcome to Django Level Two!</h1>
<h2>Here are your access records:</h2>
<div class="djangtwo">
  {% if web_records %}
  <table style="float: left">
      <thead>
          <th>Topic Name</th>
          <th>Site name</th>
          <th>Url Accessed</th>
          <th>Date Accessed</th>
          <th>Webpage nut</th>
      </thead>
  <tr>
      <td>{{ user.web.topic }}</td>  #HERE
      <td>{{ user.web.name }}</td>    #HERE
      <td>{{ user.web.url }}</td>    #HERE
      <td>{{ user.web.nut }}</td>    #HERE
      <td>{{ user.web.date }}</td>    #HERE
 </tr>
 {% endfor %}
</table>
 {% endif %}
</div>
</body>

AND IF YOU WANT LOOP,SO YOU CAN EASILY USER LOOP.
```

Comment: i wanna fill the "Date Accessed" and 'Webpage nut" columns in html template

Comment: if you could please go through my code once again and check it in your browser

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this way:

1. rename the `name` field to `web` in `AccessRecord` model.

**models.py**

```
class AccessRecord(models.Model):
      web = models.ForeignKey(Webpage)
      date = models.DateField()
      nut = models.CharField(max_length=56)

      def __str__(self):
         return str(self.date)
```

2. Get all objects of `AccessRecord` model instead of `Webpage` model.

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader

def index(request):
    access_records = AccessRecord.objects.all()
    context = { "access_records": access_records }
    t = loader.get_template('first_app/index.html')
    return HttpResponse( t.render( context, request ) )
```

3. Loop the access records in your template.

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <h1>Hi, welcome to Django Level Two!</h1>
    <h2>Here are your access records:</h2>
    <div class="djangtwo">
      {% if access_records %}
      <table style="float: left">
          <thead>
              <th>Topic Name</th>
              <th>Site name</th>
              <th>Url Accessed</th>
              <th>Date Accessed</th>
              <th>Webpage nut</th>
          </thead>
      {% for access_record in access_records %}
      <tr>
          <td>{{ access_record.web.topic }}</td>
          <td>{{ access_record.web.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ access_record.web.url }}</td>
          <td>{{ access_record.nut }}</td>
          <td>{{ access_record.date }}</td>
     </tr>
     {% endfor %}
    </table>
     {% endif %}
    </div>
    </body>
```